# Machine Learning Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

My target is a range 1 to 5. Is there a way to force to predict only in this range?

Regardless of the model I use, I sometimes get negative values ​​and values ​​greater than 5.

Comment: can you give an example of your dataframe and your algorithm you tried?

Comment: Are you conversant with the idea of a "classification model"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a model that supports multiple classes classification such as `Softmax Regression`. This algorithm is a generaliztion of Logistic regression that can classify N targets where N > 1.

The hard prediction of your model can be:

```
1 2 3 4 5
0 0 0 1 0
```

Which means that the prediction is 4

or it can be a soft prediction:

```
1   2   3   4   5
0.1 0.1 0.6 0.1 0.1
```

Which is probability and then you can know how confident is your model.

Scikit-learn implements Softmax regression within [Logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) algorithm itself by specifying the parameter `multi_class="multinomial"`